# Why do I get error Uncaugt ReferenceError while it works on other website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, inline

My goal is to get the tool working on the website: one-stop-office-shop.nl
My tool works on codepen.io (https://codepen.io/teun-van-lith/pen/mdwNYJN)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function tcoberekenen(){

const zwart=0.00849;
const kleur=0.05486;

let aantalzwart=document.rekenen.aantalzwart.value;
let aantalkleur=document.rekenen.aantalkleur.value;
var zwarttotaal=document.rekenen.zwarttotaal.value;
var kleurtotaal=document.rekenen.kleurtotaal.value;
var zwarttotaal=aantalzwart*zwart;
var kleurtotaal=aantalkleur*kleur;
var totaal=zwarttotaal+kleurtotaal;
document.rekenen.zwarttotaal.value=zwarttotaal.toFixed(2);
document.rekenen.kleurtotaal.value=kleurtotaal.toFixed(2);
document.rekenen.totaal.value=totaal.toFixed(2);
}
</script>

<div onclick="tcoberekenen()" id="rekentool"> 
  
<form name="rekenen" /><input onclick="tcoberekenen()" id="input" name="aantalzwart" /> 
<div id="inlinetext"><a id="tcotext">x zwart</a></div>
<div id="inlinetext3"><a id="tcotext">€</a></div><input id="output" name="zwarttotaal" /> <br /><input onclick="tcoberekenen()" id="input" name="aantalkleur" /> 
<div id="inlinetext"><a id="tcotext">x kleur</a></div>
<div id="inlinetext3"><a id="tcotext">€</a></div><input id="output" name="kleurtotaal" /> 
<div id="inlinetext2"><a id="tcotext">Totale afdrukkosten:</a></div>
<div id="inlinetext4"><a id="tcotext">€</a></div><input id="outputtotaal" name="totaal" /> 
</form>

</div>

<style>
#input {
border:none;     
background-image:none;     
background: #666;
height: 30px;    
width: 100px;
float:left;
color: white;
padding-left: 10px;
 }
  
#output {    
border:none;     
background-image:none;     
background: #444;
color: white;     
size="3";      
border:none;    
background-image:none;    
height: 30px;    
width: 100px;   
float:left;
}   

#outputtotaal {
border:none;     
background-image:none;     
background: #f58026;   
width: 100px;     
color: white;     
size="3";     
border:none;    
background-image:none;    
height: 30px;
float:left;
} 

#rekentool {
color: white;     
font-family: verdana;
background: #fff;
width: 340px;     
height: 160px;
float:left;
overflow: auto;
}      
  
#tcotext {
color:#fff;
text-decoration: none;
float:left;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 7px;
}

#h2tco {
color: black;
font-size: 20px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}  

#inlinetext {
float:left;
background-color: #f58026;;
width: 70px;
height: 30px;
}
  
#inlinetext2 {
float:left;
background-color: #444;
width: 170px;
height: 30px;
}
  
#inlinetext3 {
border:none;    
float:left;
background-color: #444;
width: 15px;
height: 30px;
}
  
#inlinetext4 {  
float:left;
background-color: #f58026;
width: 15px;
height: 30px;
}
</style>`
```

and in a standard html.

There is even this website where to tool works.
https://training.2thenext.nl/i/Rekentool.html

Link to website where it doesn't work:
https://www.one-stop-office-shop.nl/artikel/225638/laserprinter-brother-hl-l9310cdw.html

Error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: tcoberekenen is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (laserprinter-brother-hl-l9310cdw.html:1146)

The code is the same. I just don't get it.

Comment: We require questions here to contain all the information necessary to be able to answer it, without visiting any external links. That being said, have you checked the page source to see if the script is indeed the same? (Spoiler alert, it isn't. It seems as if the multiply operator (`*`) is replaced with `</li><li>` on your web page.)

Comment: Also the `language` attribute of the `<script>` tag has long been deprecated.

Comment: Thank you Ivar. That is a sharp note. Fixed that. BUT still getting the reference error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: tcoberekenen is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (laserprinter-brother-hl-l9310cdw.html:1146)

Comment: The failing site is getting an error saying `InitJquery` is not defined. That may be preventing all the rest of the JS from loading.

Comment: also, you have duplicate ids on HTML tags in your code, so consider replacing them with a uniqe one.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.

Does anyone know a good source of information for this error: `InitJquery is not defined`

Comment: Utmost Creator, yes. I did that on purpose because with classes it won't overrule the before made styles.